# Qt designer how to make the real size?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I model the interface and make the elements in the editor window large and convenient. But when I run the resulting program already in pycharm, the window of my program and the whole interface are several times smaller. How can I make these sizes coincide?
I can also note that the elements in the editor are clearly larger than their pixel size.
I have windows 10 and 4k monitor. The windows interface is oversized in the settings. Can this be a problem?

This is my Ui code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1074</width>
    <height>562</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="img_1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>512</width>
      <height>512</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normalon>../../Buty_frames/Leonardo_DiCaprio_1/GG0000_0.jpg</normalon>
     </iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>512</width>
      <height>512</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="img_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>550</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>512</width>
      <height>512</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normalon>../../Buty_frames/Leonardo_DiCaprio_2/GG0042_0.jpg</normalon>
     </iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>512</width>
      <height>512</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1074</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuAdd_hoto">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Add photo</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuAdd_hoto"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Pixmaps and widgets might scale differently depending on the OS font scaling and high DPI setting. Seeing your screenshot, it seems clear that the problem only relates to the images, so it might help to know how (or if) you specified the sizes of those images. Note that it would be better if you provided a [mre] (the ui file) that also includes other widgets that seem to be inconsistent with your design.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.